# Detect distance between person and painting

Tags: computer-vision, augmented-reality, distance

We're looking for solutions of detecting the distance of a person to a painting in a gallery.
The setting:

In a gallery, 12 paintings, every painting has a smartphone beneath. the closer a person is to the painting, the louder a sound will be played from the smartphone (naturally, it will be louder anyway if you're closer, but we also want to change the volume in code).

My ideas to implement this:

1. since we know the the background that the camera is filming when there's no one there, we can diff the pixels against a still of the empty room. the more pixels are different, then probably the closer a person is to the camera.
2. we could detect faces and then measure the distance between the eyes to calculate the distance

Does anyone have another idea? We're also looking at raspberry pi and sonar sensors but would prefer using smartphones to reuse old electronics and not create more electrical waste.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend you to use the easier way: a Raspberry Pi with a HC-SR04 module. Anyway, both can be used. How would I do that?

- Without computer-vision: Raspberry Pi + RPi.GPIO library + HC-SR04 module with simple code is enough: [example](https://thepihut.com/blogs/raspberry-pi-tutorials/hc-sr04-ultrasonic-range-sensor-on-the-raspberry-pi)
- Computer vision: Raspberry Pi + IMX-219 (camera) + OpenCV library.

For computer vision solution, I would use any of these [HAAR CASCADE](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/data/haarcascades) to measure distance between eyes, head sizes or something on this way. 
By using any of this HAAR CASCADE, you wouldn't need to invest so many time in things detection.

I wouldn't use a smartphone because of adapt solutions might be more difficult and expensive.